# Why am I getting an error when trying to compare to dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm supposed to:

Write a function, precipiation(d, a, b) that takes parameters:

d: Dictionary mapping a season to an amount of precipitation for that season.
a: One season
b: Another season

Your function should return True if the rainfall in season a was greater than it was in season b, and False otherwise. If the rainfall was equal, return False.

Your function should handle the following errors the following ways:

If either a or b is not a valid season in the dictionary, you should return an error message (as a string) formatted exactly as:
"Error: Key is not in Dictionary."

If the values for the rainfall in each season are not valid for comparison, that is, one of them is not a number, return an error message (as a string) formatted exactly as:
"Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?"

You may assume that no test case will produce both types of errors (so you do not need to decide whether or not to return a Key Error or Invalid Type error when you encounter both). However, you should not make any assumptions about the seasons that exist--sometimes there may be a 'potato' season.

I wrote a function that is mostly correct

```
def precipitation(d, a, b):

    try:
        if d[a] > d[b]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    except:
        if a not in d or b not in d:
            return ("Error: Key is not in Dictionary.")

        if d[a] not in (int) or d[b] not in (int):
            return ("Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?")
```

When I run this function with test case

```
precipitation({"Spring": 'cats', "Summer": 313, "Fall": 1457, "Winter": 354}, "Summer", "Spring") == 'Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?'
```

I get an error
 `argument of type 'type' is not iterable`

How can I fix this and what is causing the problem

Comment: Use good variable names. Catch the exact exception type. The problem statement does NOT specify that the datatype must be int. You need to check the types before comparing them. if-else is redundant when you just return the expression it is checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if d[a] not in (int)
```

`int` is not a container, it's a type, so `d[a]` can't be in it.*

Are you trying to make sure it's an integer? Then try `isinstance()`:

```
if not isinstance(d[a], int) ...
```

** You could write a metaclass that had a `__contains__()` method that let you treat types as containers and check for instance types in this way, which is actually a kind of interesting idea, but `int` does not do that.*

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct answers already provided,
since you are using `try` and `except`, you can also specify the type of exception for each block as well:

```py
def precipitation(d, a, b):
    try:
        return d[a] > d[b]
    except KeyError:
        return "Error: Key is not in Dictionary."
    except TypeError:
        return "Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?"
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a parameter is a specific type, use `isinstance` - `in` checks if a specific value is present in an iterable.

```
if not isinstance(d[a], int) or not isinstance(d[b], int):
    return ("Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as this is exact way of error handling

```
if ValueError:
    return ("Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?")
```

instead of

```
if if d[a] not in (int) or d[b] not in (int):
    return ("Error: Invalid data types in Dictionary?")
```

Comment: Did you mean `except ValueError`?

Comment: Yes when a value error occurs like we are comparing string with integer so its a value error so our program will jump to ValueError block.

Comment: `if ValueError` is always taken, `ValueError` is truthy.